# Navigation Controlled embedded in Container View custom segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uicontainerview

I have `UIContainerView` inside which I have `UINavigationController` and other VC embedded in `UINavigationController` (7 of them).

So, it looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of app]

On that 7 screens inside `UINavigationController` I'm calling a popup screen which then should redirect to other screen, from which user can perform back segue to the VC popup was called from.

So, user journey inside `UINavigationController` will look like: 
Opened VC1(2,3,5,6,7) -> Called popup VC -> Pressed button -> opened VC4 -> pressed navigation back button -> returned to VC1.

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func didPressAuthors(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {

        if let navigation = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            let vc1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstVC")
            let vc2 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC")
            let vc3 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdVC")
            let vc4 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FourthVC")
            let vc5 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FifthVC")
            let finalVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Authors")
            let userJourney = self.defaults.array(forKey: DefaultKeys.screenID.rawValue)

            for vcName in userJourney! {
                switch String(describing: vcName) {
                case "FirstVC":
                    self.journeyVC.append(vc1)
                case "SecondVC":
                    self.journeyVC.append(vc2)
                case "ThirdVC":
                    self.journeyVC.append(vc3)
                case "FourthVC":
                    self.journeyVC.append(vc4)
                case "FifthVC":
                    self.journeyVC.append(vc5)
                default:
                    self.journeyVC.append(finalVC)
                }
            }
            self.journeyVC.append(finalVC)
            navigation.setViewControllers(self.journeyVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

When I didn't have `UINavigationController` inside `UIContainerView` this code worked just fine, but after I had added `Container View` - it stopped. Dismiss func is called, but nothing happens. What I'm missing? Should I change how VC is presented?

Would be grateful if anyone could help me fix this issue. Many thanks and have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current root isn't the navigation here

```
if let navigation = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
```

it's a usual VC that the navigation is inserted as a child so try

```
if let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? RootVC {
let nav = root.children![0] as! UINavigationController
```

Comment: That what I was missing. Many thanks for rapid response and nice fix!